# Get Last ID From The table [ Entity Framework ]

Tags: database, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

Could someone guide me on this. I am using EntityFramwork4 , I want to get the ID of the last row of a table. Could someone having experience using this tell me , how can i get the last id from a database table.

Comment: @Mitch , yes i need Max ID, which means last id. is there a method called max

Comment: @Kltis, why do you want to get the max ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Relational databases have no intrinsic order. There is no such thing as "the last row." Even if there were, multiuser concurrency would make this meaningless.

`Max(id)` *probably* doesn't solve your issue due to concurrency. But since you haven't told us what the real problem you're trying to solve **is,** it's hard to be sure.

Comment: "Relational databases have no intrinsic order" - Tables in SQL Server do if they have a clustered index defined.

Comment: @Mitch, I know, but that's an implementation detail. The general case is still as I stated it. Also, it's not actually what @Kltis wants, I think. He's really looking for *his* last record, not *the* last record. Using `Max(id)` is a very bad idea. In addition to being likely wrong, it can be slow even when it does work.

Comment: @Craig: " it can be slow " - sure anything can be slow. Depends on size of table, indexes, Server RAM etc...

Comment: @Craig: You said "Relational databases have no intrinsic order" - that implies an implementation. We don't normally talk about Theoretical Relational databases.

Comment: @Mitch: That there *might* be a clustered index does not necessarily imply that the "last" record in that index is either the "last" record the user inserted or the "last" record in the order he expects. I **suspect** he's looking for something along the lines of `SCOPE_IDENTITY`, but it's really hard to tell based on the minimal information in the question. It is doing @Kltis no favors to give answers to the wrong question. In other words: If he's really looking for `SCOPE_IDENTITY`, then using `.Max()` is the *wrong* way to do it.

Comment: @Craig Stuntz : the poster states " I want to get the ID of the last row of a table" - that implies they want the highest ID, not the Id of the last inserted record.

Comment: @Mitch: I can read. Misusing `Max` for `SCOPE_IDENTITY` is a *classic* mistake. Until he says why he wants the "last" record, there's not an answer I can be confident about.