# c#: getting the last id of an entity (LINQ2SQL)

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-4

i looked a bit around stackoverflow to find an answer for my question.
All what i found is this: [Get Last ID From The table [ Entity Framework ]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975520/get-last-id-from-the-table-entity-framework)

This is exactly what i need.. but there is no answer for this question.. seems that the guy who asked the question didnt explain why he needs it.

I am coding a ticket system for my company.

Now if someone creats a ticket i want him not to type in the Ticket ID (Ticket #) by himself.. i want a textbox which is Enabled = false. It should automatically be filled with the new Ticket ID (it must be the last Ticket ID + 1).

This is the reason why i am looking for the last id of my entity.

i tryed out this:

```
var ticketNrQuery = (from tn in kdVerwaltung.Ticket
                     orderby tn.Ticket_ID
                     select tn).Last();
textBoxTicketNr.Text = (ticketNrQuery.Ticket_ID + 1).ToString();
```

in this sample i get an unsupported exception (what the hell).

Any solutions for my problem?

Comment: Be careful around the fact that if two people hit the site at once, they'll both get the same new ticket number.  The best thing is to let the database set the ticket numbers (using an IDENTITY) and then display it to the user after their ticket has been saved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [MAX()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549271.aspx) since it can be translated to SQL:

```
var maxTicketId = kdVerwaltung.Ticket.Max(x => x.Ticket_ID) + 1;
```

That will be translated into the following query:

```
SELECT MAX([t0].Ticket_ID) as [value] FROM [dbo].[YourTable] AS [t0]
```

You  should profile this if you're going to use it in production. Using MAX can be pretty slow if you have *a lot* of rows.

Comment: what will happen in a case if there is no data in the database( like the user is creating the first ticket) ?

Comment: @darkdog If `Ticket_ID` is a value type (not nullable), you'll get a InvalidOperationException. If it's nullable, you'll get a less optimal query.

Answer (score 1):

```
        Int32? newID = (from ticket in kdVerwaltung.Ticket select (int?)ticket.ID).Max();
        newID = newID.HasValue ? newID.Value + 1 : 1;
```

Comment: Int64 newID = (kdVerwaltung.Ticket != null && kdVerwaltung.Ticket.Count() > 0) ? kdVerwaltung.Ticket.Max(x => x.Ticket_ID) + 1 : 1;